# Run jQuery code after render template in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'fx-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/modules/main/page.html',
    directives: [RouterOutlet,RouterLink,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        HTTP_PROVIDERS
    ]
})

export class MainComponent {
    constructor(){
        var menu = new MainMenu();
    }
}
```

With its template `app/modules/main/page.htm`:

```
<div id="menu">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="menuContainer">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="withNested closed">
                    <span class="word">Users</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a [routerLink]="['Products']">
                    <span class="word">Products</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

<div id="footer"></div>
```

Class `MainMenu` looks like this:

```
export class MainMenu{

    public menu = null;
    public allLinks = null;

    constructor(){
        this.menu = $('#menu');
        this.allLinks = $('#menu').find('a');
        this.menu.find('ul a').click(this.setItem);
        console.log('init MainMenu');
    }

    public setItem (){
        this.allLinks.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        if($(this).hasClass('withNested')){
            if($(this).hasClass('opened')){
                $(this).removeClass('opened');
                $(this).addClass('closed');
                $(this).next('ul').slideUp();
            }else{
                $(this).removeClass('closed');
                $(this).addClass('opened');
                $(this).next('ul').slideDown();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Code of class  `MainMenu` does not work, because it works before the displayed  template `app/modules/main/page.htm`. How to make that jQuery-code of class `MainMenu` started to work correctly?

Comment: @Meiko, NO! your link for Angular 1.x!

Comment: sorry, yes you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use one of the events available on a **component life cycle**, a good resource is http://learnangular2.com/lifecycle/ .

By the way, just a note, you are using jQuery for DOM access and you shouldn't do that. You should stay in the Angular Environment, try to avoid accessing dom directly.

Comment: How to access DOM in angular2, if we should not use jquery?

Comment: Simply because you have a data-binding system between your model and your view, so, instead of doing `jQuery(...).removeClass()` set a property in your model and provide a statement in your view, like `ngClass` that checks that model property...

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use ngOnInit() as it fires as soon as the dom is ready:

```
import {OnInit} from 'angular2/core';

export class MainMenu implements OnInit {

    public menu = null;
    public allLinks = null;

    constructor(){

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.menu = $('#menu');
        this.allLinks = $('#menu').find('a');
        this.menu.find('ul a').click(this.setItem.bind(this));
        console.log('init MainMenu');
    }

    public setItem (e){
        this.allLinks.removeClass('active');
        $(e.currentTarget).addClass('active');
        if($(e.currentTarget).hasClass('withNested')){
            if($(e.currentTarget).hasClass('opened')){
                $(e.currentTarget).removeClass('opened');
                $(e.currentTarget).addClass('closed');
                $(e.currentTarget).next('ul').slideUp();
            }else{
                $(e.currentTarget).removeClass('closed');
                $(e.currentTarget).addClass('opened');
                $(e.currentTarget).next('ul').slideDown();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: or `var menu = new MainMenu();` lives in the ngOnInit

Comment: It is not work! Him say: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeClass' of undefined`

Comment: well it does work... Its probably a scope issue now. Look at my second answer to probably fix that error